# Fax a HTML page via RightFax COM API

Tags: html, rightfax

I tried to fax a HTML page via RightFax COM API by supplying the HTML page as an attchment. However, the fax generated contains the HTML source code.

I've done some research. It looks like 2 options are available: 1) HTML to image 2) HTML to PDF, then send the image or PDF to RightFax.

Still wonder if anyone has any experience of using RightFax COM API to fax the rendered HTML page successfully in any other approach other the two options above.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just to update that after some more researching, I found that MHTML is the way to go.